# Why I'm getting a HTTP ERROR 500 in Godaddy Server?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, memory

Firstly This is not a duplicate!

Tried All possible things given on **StackOverflow** and **magento.stackexchange** for this but none of it solved my issue.
[image: Issue]
Getting HTTP 500 error when accessing register page and when accessing checkout page.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3097 bytes) in /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Abstract.php on line 98
```

1. Checked throttling checked php.ini , checked .htaccess for memory things and all.
2. Checked config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line/file that you have an issue is responsible for loading the variables and remove the comment lines on your email template, try to use the default template for emails sent on checkout (e.g. create account, new order and etc.),

---

If doesn't resolve you can add much more limits to your `memory_limit` to test.

Increase these values in you `.htaccess`

```
php_value memory_limit 512M
php_value max_execution_time 38000
```

If the changes above doesn't resolve it, use this command to find your `php.ini` and increase these values above.

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```

Comment: Plz read I mentioned I HV already changed thsese thing but it's same.

Comment: This line/file that you have an issue is responsible for loading the variables and remove the comment lines on your email template, try to use the default template for emails sent on checkout (e.g. create account, new order and etc.), if doesn't resolve you can add much more limits to your memory_limit to test.